# Pass QNetworkReply pointer to QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qnetworkaccessmanager, qsharedpointer

One question about use of `QSharedPointer` in following scenario:

I have a class with two `QSharedPointer`s private class members:

```
class xy{

...

private:
    QSharedPointer<QNetworkAccessManager>   m_nam;
    QSharedPointer<QNetworkReply>           m_nr;
};
```

In the code I send a `QNetworkAccessManager` post, the return value is a `QNetworkReply` pointer.

```
QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest & request, const QByteArray & data)
```

I want to to pass this pointer to my `QSharedPointer` i.e. `m_nr`.
I tried:

```
m_nam.reset( new QNetworkAccessManager(m_parent.data()));
QNetworkRequest request(url);
...
...
// following line is my problem
m_nr = QSharedPointer<QNetworkReply>(m_nam->post(request, postData));
...
```

But crashed, then I tried:

```
m_nam.reset( new QNetworkAccessManager(m_parent.data()));
QNetworkRequest request(url);
...
...
// following line is my problem
m_nr.reset( m_nam->post(request, postData));
...
```

But also crashed.

How to pass `QNetworkReply` pointer correctly to my `QSharedPointer`?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Should be enough example code, i think

Answer (score 0):

What is the error on crash??
Is it exactly crashing at the line you mentioned.

Be carefull in Qt to combine smart pointers and QObjects parenting.
Parenting in Qt affects object freeing with some kind of pseudo garbage collection. 
All children of a deleted QObject are deleted as well. 
Combining this with QSharedPointer for example might result in multiple object free or access after free kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, it crashes exactly at this line i mentioned. For the moment i dont use smart pointer but QNetworkReply pointer instead to pass the result from "m_nam->post()". Because of no time at the moment. I will later on continue with this issue...